# How to create a python venv Docker that can be used as a general purpose venv

Tags: python, docker, python-venv

I am trying to create a python venv in docker to avoid adding stuff and files to my local (as I always struggle to remove all the files when willing to get rid of python or a venv overall).
I know I can isolate the venv using Conda, but I want to focus on Docker, as it may be the case that I want to use it alongside some other techs.

So far I have been able to run a container with a requirements.txt by means of the following Dockerfile:

```
# Usa una imagen base de Python
FROM python:3.8

# Establece el directorio de trabajo
WORKDIR /app

# Copia el archivo requirements.txt al contenedor
COPY requirements.txt .

# Instala las dependencias en el entorno virtual
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN /bin/bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt"

# Expone el puerto si es necesario
# EXPOSE 8000

# Inicia la aplicación (puedes modificarlo según tus necesidades)
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

and then docker build and docker run

I also use the remote explorer and docker extensions in VSCode in order to manage the container.

The problem comes when I want to somehow connect this venv to VSCode, just like I would do with a locally created venv, and then run a very simple script where I only import some libraries (simply for testing purposes).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

I tried to load the venv once the container is up and running in Docker, and expected to be able to deal with script files as I would do if the venv would have been created locally

Comment: Python's venvs are used to isolate different setups from one another. Docker achieves the same, but not specifically for Python. Why use both?

Comment: I do not want to create local vevns. Being able to create venvs through Docker that can be used in local python projects, if possible, is a much cleaner way. At least for small custom projects. It may be not be specific for python, but I dont see any problem in using it for it

Comment: If you have a host virtual environment, you can just delete it (`rm -rf`) when you're done with it, or if you need to re-do the dependency installation from scratch, or otherwise need to recreate it.  IME this is much easier than trying to convince an isolated Docker container to work on host code with full tooling and IDE support.